# Expand google maps circle while mouse pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to draw a circle when a user long presses on the map. The circle will grow the longer the mouse button is held down.

Then on mouse up i want to stop the circle growing and get its bounds.

Here it is so far - http://jsfiddle.net/Ss8xe/1/

```
new LongPress(map, 500);
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'longpress', function(e) {
      var radius = 100;
      // Draw a circle around the radius
      var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: e.latLng,
        radius: radius,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#0000FF",
        fillOpacity: 0.4
       });          
       circle.setMap(map);  

    var t;
    var start =  2;
    var speedup =  4;
    var grow = function () {
        radius = radius + 50;
        circle.setRadius(radius);
        t = setTimeout(grow, start);
        start = start / speedup;
    }
    grow();
});
```

I am having trouble detecting the mouse up to stop the circle growing? "mouseup" doesnt seem to fire after "longpress"

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's you go...you need to add `clickable:false` to circle, without that the circle will listen for mouse-events and the mouseup-event will fire on the circle and not on the map.

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ss8xe/9/)

**JS:**

```
var map = null;

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.435833800555567, -80.44189453125),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 11
    };

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

    new LongPress(map, 500);
    var t;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'longpress', function (e) {
        var radius = 100;
        // Draw a circle around the radius
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: e.latLng,
            radius: radius,
            strokeColor: "#0000FF",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#0000FF",
            fillOpacity: 0.4,
            clickable: false
        });
        circle.setMap(map);
        var start = 2;
        var speedup = 4;
        var grow = function () {
            radius = radius + 50;
            circle.setRadius(radius);
            t = setTimeout(grow, start);
            start = start / speedup;
        }
        grow();
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function (e) {
         clearTimeout(t);
    });

}

function LongPress(map, length) {
    this.length_ = length;
    var me = this;
    me.map_ = map;
    me.timeoutId_ = null;
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mousedown', function (e) {
        me.onMouseDown_(e);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'mouseup', function (e) {
        me.onMouseUp_(e);
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'drag', function (e) {
        me.onMapDrag_(e);
    });
};
LongPress.prototype.onMouseUp_ = function (e) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId_);
};
LongPress.prototype.onMouseDown_ = function (e) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId_);
    var map = this.map_;
    var event = e;
    this.timeoutId_ = setTimeout(function () {
        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'longpress', event);
    }, this.length_);
};
LongPress.prototype.onMapDrag_ = function (e) {
    clearTimeout(this.timeoutId_);
};
```